# Recover files from External HDD to DVD+RW using Photorec

Tags: data-recovery

So I have a 1 TB external hard drive which I accidentally formatted back when I was using Windows 8. I moved to Ubuntu afterwards and haven't touched the external HDD for a few days.

I now want to use photorec to recover my files. My only problem is that I have no storage large enough except for a DVD+RW (internal drive 500G).

I already got photorec up and running. I am just stuck at the final option, where to save the recovered files.

I can't find a way to use the DVD+RW as a writable drive.

questions:
Where is the DVD directory in the file system?
How do I make the DVD function like a flash drive?

Answer (score 2):

> We can not use a DVD/RW to save our recovered files.

In case the files you need to recover are worth it you should get another external drive to hold all the data.

Another possibility it running **testdisk** from the same application suit. With this application you may be able to recover your partition table to access files. You can also restore single files on your internal drive from running testdisk.

See: [How do I recover my accidentally lost Windows partitions after installing Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/286181/how-do-i-recover-my-accidentally-lost-windows-partitions-after-installing-ubuntu)

> To avoid data loss it still is strongly recommendend to run testdisk on an image of your drive rather than on the original drive.

Answer (score 0):

One more application which user can also try, i had used this utility and got satisfied results. It is available as a Free Trial Version. 
http://www.recoverydeletedfiles.com/

Thanks