# data recovery with testdisk

Tags: partitioning, data-recovery, testdisk

I'm trying to recover my data after a bad installation. On my laptop I had 2 partitions: Windows and Media. Now I'm trying to recover the content of the Media partition and this is what the amazing TestDisk has found: 2 Media partitions.

I don't know which should be the next step and I'm afraid to do experiments in order to no loose all my data from Media partition.

[image]

Comment: Press "P" to list files - this will hopefully tell you from which partition you want to recover. Also see: http://askubuntu.com/questions/400150/how-to-resolve-the-harddisk-seems-too-small-with-testdisk-deeper-search

Answer (score 1):

You will find some useful solutions in these two questions, including instructions on how to proceed with `testdisk`:

- [Recover files from External HDD to DVD+RW using Photorec](https://askubuntu.com/questions/390741/recover-files-from-external-hdd-to-dvdrw-using-photorec)
- [How do I recover my accidentally lost Windows partitions after installing Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/286181/how-do-i-recover-my-accidentally-lost-windows-partitions-after-installing-ubuntu)

Answer (score 0):

Its obvious to show two partitions and maybe more... that is due to making the same partition before the current state with the same characteristics but differ in the end 
sector.

Anyway, You are making recovery so why you are afraid?!

Just move on and choose anyway one. when the recovery process is complete the testdisk will prompt you with the result and asks you were to save the recovered data...

What i wanna say to you that testdisk will not write to the recovered partition so even you choose a wrong one, this will not hurt your data.. so you can choose the other then.

Comment: -1. It is usually not considered a good idea to do recovery directly from the damaged media. More often than not you're advised to first make a copy of the image on a different disk, and then attempt to recover from there.

Comment: @landroni have you downvoted also the other answers!!! Anyway, sure its the best practice to take an image BUT READ THE QUEST ABOVE BEFORE. The image is better when u talk about hardware failure not just simple recovery so don't think that u r that smart guy. I have worked 6 years in data recovery domain and forensics and i know verywell what i'm talking about and PLEASE note i dont care for your -1 since it's not logical