# How to recover a deleted Folder(/Desktop in this case)

Tags: command-line, bash, 14.10, undelete

I have accidentally deleted(in a way) or I can say dislocated reference to my /home/user/Desktop directory , Is there any way to undo what I have done.

The following Describes what I have done

```
$ cp xyz.java /home/user/Desktop
$ cp xyz1.java /home/user/Desktop
```

After these commands I am getting blank Desktop With wallpaper and when I try to open my Desktop Directory by

`cd /home/user/Desktop`

command it gives following `not a directory` error

`bash: cd: /home/user/Desktop: Not a directory`

PS: Before copying the file to correct `Desktop` Directory I mis-spelled `Desktop` as `Deskop` and system Created a file name `Deskop` in my `/home/user` folder when I opened it, the file contained data of `xyz.java` in it.

could anyone guide me through this and also please tell me what happened to my Desktop files and If, they are now orphaned in my memory How do i restore them.I have one more question in my mind after this Disaster:

How do I undo the commands and their execution results with command-line?

Comment: `cp` never deletes an existing directory. Either this wasn't the only thing you did, or something else happened that makes that directory inaccessible.

Comment: @Rinzwind- Yes I actually used "user" which is my username

Comment: what should I do?? I don't want empty Desktop.. Is there any way to recover from this?

Comment: @Creator doubt it. But there is a tool called "testdisk" (have a search on AU for it) that can restore deleted files. That might be your best best.

Comment: have a look here for restoring: http://askubuntu.com/questions/3883/how-to-recover-deleted-files

Comment: @Rinzwind `http://askubuntu.com/questions/403883/data-recovery-with-testdisk` is this what you talking about

Comment: That is another one yes. it is a bit complicated to use though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I doubt these commands did anything:

```
rinzwind@schijfwereld:~$ mkdir test
rinzwind@schijfwereld:~$ touch test1
rinzwind@schijfwereld:~$ cp test1 test
rinzwind@schijfwereld:~$ ls -l test*
-rw-rw-r-- 1 rinzwind rinzwind    0 feb  8 20:20 test1

test:
total 0
-rw-rw-r-- 1 rinzwind rinzwind 0 feb  8 20:20 test1
rinzwind@schijfwereld:~$ cd test
rinzwind@schijfwereld:~/test$ ls
test1
rinzwind@schijfwereld:~/test$
```

Directory `test` is still there and has `test1` in it.

Before you continue  do a

```
ls -l ~
```

and examine the results. There should be a

```
drwxrwxr-x 2 rinzwind rinzwind 4096 feb  8 20:20 Desktop
```

The "d" makes it a directory. If that is the case all is well.

If not and it shows a "-" (aka. it has become a file) ... do (as rthe user you want this desktop created ($USER will be expand to that user name)):

```
cd ~
rm /home/$USER/Desktop
mkdir Desktop
```

(do not add `-r` to the `rm`) as the user that is suppose to own this directory. Otherwise add in

```
chown $USER:$USER Desktop
```

Warning: if you do this with a directory the "rm" will fail with an error stating you are trying to delete a directory. This will have you restore to an EMPTY desktop. If you had files in there they are gone.

---

From comments

```
-rw-r--r--  1 root       root        Desktop
```

Put "sudo" in front of the "rm" above. So ...

```
cd ~
sudo rm /home/$USER/Desktop
mkdir Desktop
```

Comment: chmod: invalid mode: ‘root:root’
Try 'chmod --help' for more information.

Comment: Do not do this are root please.

Comment: I did it and got a new Desktop Folder all my stuff is lost and what is major reason not to work (unnecessarily) as root?