# Restoring Deleted Home folder content

Tags: restore

I was trying to delete a directory that I made using catkin_make( so I asked google)
I used the fallowing code in catkin_workspace
$ sudo rm -rf *
I got trolled and deleted everything in Home

Is there a way to restore the Home folder?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/31450/tool-for-recovering-deleted-data-from-a-flash-drive/31453#31453

Answer (score 1):

The default files inside your home folder will be re-created when you log in again. Do not do that since it might make it impossible to recover your personal data.

As for your personal documents: preferred method would be to restore those from a backup. If you do not have any you will need to rely on software like [testdisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) to find those files. Topics on recovering data:

- [How to recover deleted files?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3883/how-to-recover-deleted-files) (Using scalpel)
- [data recovery with testdisk](https://askubuntu.com/questions/403883/data-recovery-with-testdisk) (Using testdisk)
- [General wiki page on data recovery](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DataRecovery).

Recovery tools work best if you did nothing with the space the deleted files occupied on disk.