# How to recover data when ubuntu os is overwritten on ubuntu server?

Tags: 14.04, data-recovery, data-loss

My system was pre-installed with ubuntu server. I replaced the ubuntu server with a fresh ubuntu-desktop 18.04 installation. I created a partition for `boot/efi` as FAT32. While performing installation all my data was deleted. How can I get back this data. Can some one suggest stepwise method to recover my data from whole drive :( ...

Comment: Your details seem unclear to me; Ubuntu 18.04 LTS desktop won't install itself to a FAT32 partition so your question is somewhat unclear.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [data recovery with testdisk](https://askubuntu.com/questions/403883/data-recovery-with-testdisk)

Comment: I created a partition for `boot/efi` as FAT32.

Comment: This answer may also help you: https://askubuntu.com/a/425646/3940

Comment: Just restore your data from a recent backup ...

Comment: @guiverc I tried testdisk as per given instructions: It gives a message "following partions can't be recoverd" and gives list of partitions